# Отключить autoindent в VS 2015+

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vb.net, visual-studio-2017, форматирование

Как отключить автоматическую установку отступа у кода на VB.NET в Visual Sudio 2015? Ужасно бесит, что из-за недописнных конструкций отступы получаются неправильными.

[image: скринвидео]

Вроде бы smart отключил, но не помогает:

[image: скриншот настроек Tabs]

[image: скриншот настроек Advanced]

Comment: В Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic > Advanced - Editor Help не смотрели?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, эм.. нашёл отключение вообще всего автоформатирования - он даже регистр букв перестаёт исправлять :( Мне бы только отступы отключить, как я в VS2010 делал...

Comment: Странно. `Indenting=Block` у меня приносит ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Можете проверить не проставлено ли выравнивание (Indenting) для всех языков (`Text Editor > All Languages > Tabs`)?

Comment: @defaultlocale, а разве настройки для специфического языка не приоритетнее настроек для всех? В all languages в tabs вообще ничего не задано.